# Interpolating NaNs in pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe:

```
                vals 
2017-07-08  0.169524 
2017-07-09  0.167619 
2017-07-10  0.165714 
2017-07-11  0.163810 
2017-07-12  0.161905
```

Based on [Extend pandas datetime index to present date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122505/extend-pandas-datetime-index-to-present-date), I extend the index to present day and then I want to fill in values by interpolation. I do this:

```
df.interpolate(how='bicubic', inplace=True)
```

and get this:

```
               vals
2017-07-11  0.163810
2017-07-12  0.161905
2017-07-13  0.161905
2017-07-14  0.161905
2017-07-15  0.161905
```

However, I want the last 3 values from `2017-07-13` to `2017-07-15` not to be the same as the value for `2017-07-12` but be based on whatever trend was happening over the last few values. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is actually extrapolation, not interpolation, and unfortunately `pnd.DataFrame` does not have a method for it.

You will need to define an extrapolation model, for example by fitting a polynomial curve from your known data and extrapolating it to the remaining index. There is nice explanation on how to do this with time-series indexes [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34159342/extrapolate-pandas-dataframe/35960833#35960833).